# binding data from sub query?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, angularjs

Screen shot
[image]
Image 1

[image]

So this (Image 1) is "Network" preview of data. So I have data in `mySQL` database and I am importing it with php. Because of some reasons I had to make 2 sub queries. Now I get data like on image. Main query is "data" then 2 of sub are "devices" and "units". Now I can't call "devices" and "units" with ng-repeat for unknown reason. I tried like `ng-repeat="x in data.devices"` and some other ways but things just don't show in on my page. NOTE! I get data from main query "data" so things like IP, credential and USER_ID is shown. Result is Image 2 but should look like image 3.

Thanks !

Comment: can you give api calling link where i get this json

Comment: try `ng-repeat="x in data[0].devices"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `data` is an *array*, try `ng-repeat="x in data[0].devices"`

Comment: It is working, the only thing I had to change is to put [$index] instead of [0]. Thanks @DonJuwe !